# R Side-by-Side Boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm sure this is a very simple question for most of you, but I'm new and can't figure it out. How do you create a side by side box plot grouped by time? For example, I have 24 months of data. I want to make one box plot for the first 12 months, and another for the second 12 months. My data can be seen below.

```
Month,Revenue
1,94000
2,81000
3,117000
4,105000
5,117000
6,89000
7,101000
8,118000
9,105000
10,123000
11,109000
12,89000
13,106000
14,159000
15,121000
16,135000
17,116000
18,133000
19,144000
20,130000
21,142000
22,124000
23,140000
24,104000
```

Comment: When asking for help with plotting you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. That makes it much easier to test possible solutions and verify they work.

Comment: Maybe just `boxplot(Revenue~I((Month-1)%/%12+1), df)`, if your data frame is called `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data has a time ordering, it might be illuminating to plot line plots by month for each year separately. Here is code for both a line plot and a boxplot. I just made up the year values in the code below, but you can make those whatever is appropriate:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Assuming your data frame is called "dat"
dat$Month.abb = month.abb[rep(1:12,2)]
dat$Month.abb = factor(dat$Month.abb, levels=month.abb)
dat$Year = rep(2014:2015, each=12)

ggplot(dat, aes(Month.abb, Revenue, colour=factor(Year))) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Year)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(dat$Revenue))) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(colour="Year", x="Month")

ggplot(dat, aes(factor(Year), Revenue)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(dat$Revenue))) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Year")
```

[image]